# Calculate Compressibility of water

Tags: pressure, water, volume

I have **1 litre** of water on **30 celsius**, and there is a pressure of **10 mega psi** affects on it. I want to calculate volume decrease that caused by pressure

Thanks

Comment: Please excuse my poor English

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Comment: I do not want to make my homework and this is not homework at all, I want to learn How to calculate not the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compression of a substance (liquid or solid) under pressure is described by the [bulk modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus), $K$. The bulk modulus is a function of the compression, so the compression is given by a differential equation:

$$ \frac{\text{d}V}{V} = -\frac{\text{d}P}{K} \tag{1} $$

In many cases we can approximate $K$ as constant, in which case equation (1) becomes:

$$ \frac{\Delta V}{V_0} = -\frac{\Delta P}{K} \tag{1} $$

where $V_0$ is the original volume.

So to do your calculation you just need to Google for the bulk modulus of water in the pressure range you're interested in.

Your question could be interpreted as asking how you calculate the bulk modulus from first principles. This would require a quantum mechanics calculation of the structure of the material. You'd need a biiiiiig computer!